# In DataTables how to pass a variable to aaSorting

Tags: javascript, datatables

I use dataTables in my project (link for this plugin: http://legacy.datatables.net/ref).
I need to get a list from ajax and assign this value to aaSorting. Like

```
var sortOrder = [];
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:  getSortOrderUrl,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        sortOrder = result;
    }
});
console.log(sortOrder); // is [[2,'asc'], [3,'desc']]
var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
    ...
    "aaSorting": sortOrder,
    ...
});
```

It doesn't work :(

---

How could I get the table attributes like aaSorting? I cannot use `console.log(table.aaSorting)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until ajax is done before building your table so that the variable is available:

```
success: function (result) {
    sortOrder = result;

    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable({
        ...
        "aaSorting": sortOrder,
        ...
    });
}
```

Comment: It has a error called: DataTables warning: table id={id} - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

Comment: That would seem to indicate that you're initializing twice. Did you remove the original init function when you added it to the ajax callback?

Comment: I just have one initializion. And then added the ajax outside this initializion as above.